# Virtual HostX and MAMP not working with Wordpress

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

Virtual HostX and MAMP does not render the Wordpress files. Virtual HostX and MAMP are both set to port 80. However, the MAMP's Apache is not running. And MAMP's web server is set to `htdocs` folder

The URL is displaying - It Works! after refresh:

[image]

however it should prompt me to set up Wordpress like so:

[image]

Folder structure, as per the video tutorial:

[image]

VirtualHostX and MAMP setup:

[image]

I have followed every single step as it is in this Tutorial, multiple times, it still is not working.

Tutorial:
https://vimeo.com/39957172

Please advise.

Comment: find a better tutorial ;). This is a general web server setting issue and out of scope here

Comment: that's the problem, there is none...

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting to use MAMP, but VirtualHostX shows that Apple's built-in Apache is running. You'll need to stop it by running this command in a Terminal window...

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Then, start MAMP using their control panel and try again.

Also, make sure "MAMP" is set as your "Default Web Server" in VirtualHostX's Preferences window.

Comment: Hi Tyler, Thak you for looking into this. I did stop the Apple apache runnining, teh set up the MAMP and VirtualHostX as you instruted, however I still get the - Index Of/ now however, as you can see from the screenshot. Im really puzzled of why its like that. Could it be my Mac setup? User setup? See this screengrab for all the sofware running correctly: http://i.imgur.com/cHZRfg9.png

Comment: aaaand, now its back to (It works!) again, with exact same setup...   http://i.imgur.com/Zlrgov9.png